# setting up a domain server using windows server 2012 r2 VM

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller

I am getting ready to setup a server with 2012 r2 VM and im thinking about changing our network over to a domain. I have done some research but have not found a really good tutorial.

The questions i have are

Do i only have to run the Active Directory
Do i have to run a DNS?
Is there a good tutorial online that anyone knows about?

Comment: This should help: http://www.rebeladmin.com/2014/07/step-by-step-guide-to-setup-active-directory-on-windows-server-2012/ or http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-active-directory-on-windows-server-2012 both are good tutorials.
!0 seconds google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, running Active Directory does require a DNS server. If you install the AD DS role from the Server Manager wizard, it will automatically add the DNS server role as well.

Your second question is not really on topic for Server Fault according to the question guidelines: https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic